# 500 Internal server error when running mod_wsgi, django, apache2 on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, django, apache, raspberry-pi, mod-wsgi

I am getting the internal server error when I try to create a site using virtual host on my raspberry pi.

/var/www/djangohoneypi.com/logs/error.log ->

```
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.136935 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=2401): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/djangohoneypi.co$
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.137306 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.137453 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 158, i$
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.143698 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.143838 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in$
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.146514 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.146787 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __ge$
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.148706 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.148813 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _set$
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.148966 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.149040 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __in$
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.149162 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.149235 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.150757 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     __import__(name)
[Tue Jun 21 15:06:28.150931 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2401] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ImportError: No module named settings
```

My apache2 error.log shows this->

```
    [Tue Jun 21 11:57:04.983714 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6360] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Jun 21 11:57:06.483744 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 6547] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 11:57:06.483905 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 6547] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 11:57:06.505909 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6547] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 11:57:06.506092 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6547] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:00:58.259467 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6911] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Jun 21 14:00:59.802718 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7390] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:00:59.802865 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7390] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:00:59.825458 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7390] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:00:59.825659 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7390] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:42.055490 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7390] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:43.590752 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7512] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:43.590900 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7512] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:43.613120 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7512] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:43.613300 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:49.331150 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7512] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa$
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:49.807480 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7512] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:49.807593 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7512] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:49.810961 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7512] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:03:49.811126 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:54.744507 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7512] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa$
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:55.252913 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7512] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:55.253034 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7512] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:55.256293 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7512] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:55.256436 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:57.300431 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7512] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:58.872713 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:58.872854 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:58.895435 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:04:58.895633 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7763] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:16:53.836865 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa$
    [Tue Jun 21 14:16:54.333708 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:16:54.333830 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:16:54.337114 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:16:54.337261 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7763] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:18:03.191606 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa$
    [Tue Jun 21 14:18:03.627928 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:18:03.628040 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:18:03.631401 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:18:03.631559 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7763] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Jun 21 14:24:46.419472 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messa$
    [Tue Jun 21 14:24:46.831800 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:24:46.831909 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7763] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
    [Tue Jun 21 14:24:46.835197 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7763] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Jun 21 14:24:46.835346 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7763] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/djangohoneypi.com.conf ->

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName djangohoneypi.com
        ServerAdmin admin@djangohoneypi.com
        ServerAlias www.djangohoneypi.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/public_html
        ErrorLog /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/logs/access.log combined

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        WSGIDaemonProcess djangohoneypi.com threads=5
        WSGIProcessGroup djangohoneypi.com

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/application/django.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/application>
            WSGIProcessGroup djangohoneypi.com
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

#       WSGIDaemonProcess djangohoneypi.com threads=5
#       WSGIProcessGroup djangohoneypi.com
        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/public_html/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/public_html/favicon.ico
        Alias /images /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/public_html/images
        Alias /static /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/public_html/static

        #ErrorLog /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/logs/error.log
        #CustomLog /var/www/djangohoneypi.com/logs/access.log combined

        #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/var/www/djangohoneypi.com/application/django.wsgi ->

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/djangohoneypi.com/application')
sys.path.append('/var/www')
sys.path.append('/var/www/djangohoneypi.com')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/www/djangohoneypi.com/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'HoneyPi.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Please help me figure out what's going wrong.